# TFS 2017 JQuery call REST API

Tags: jquery, ajax, tfs

Привет всем, по ссылке [Get started with the REST APIs](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/rest/basics) есть пример вызова через JQuery REST API TFS 2017, где присутствует myPatToken, не понятно что это за атрибут и где его посмотреть?

```js
 $.ajax({
            url: 'https://fabrikam.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection/_apis/projects?api-version=1.0',
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa("" + ":" + myPatToken)
            }
        }).done(function( results ) {
            console.log( results.value[0].id + " " + results.value[0].name );
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Под примером написано (replace **myPatToken** with a personal access token)

На этой же страничке есть сслыка [create a personal access token](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/authentication/pats)

Comment: Спасибо.......)